# How to find a subset of cells in an html table? using R or JQuery

Tags: jquery, r

In an html page I have one huge table (only one table) and I need to access only one of the cells. For example the following code is two rows of this table with 6 columns.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
      Type1                                                                    
    </td>
    <td>
      103
    </td>                                
    <td>                                    
      153                                                                        
    </td>                                
    <td>
      N/A
    </td>
    <td align = "center">
      NA
    </td>
    <td align = "center">
      1
    </td>
</tr>                            
<tr>
    <td>                                  
      Type2                                                                    
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>                                
    <td>                                    
      220                                                                        
    </td>                                
    <td>
      243
    </td>
    <td align = "center">
      abc
    </td>
    <td align = "center">
      100
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I find the value "103" (the second column of the row header "Type1")? Is this possible to be done in R (XML library) if not JQuery would also be fine. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread/misunderstood what you were asking.  If you want the value '103' and you have 'Type1' you can use this to return the value of the `td` after the `td` that contains 'Type1':

```
$("td:contains('Type1')").next("td").text()
```

---

I'm not sure about R, but in jQuery there's the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

`$("td:contains('103')")` should select it.

Comment: @dave thanks for your response, how can I find "103" by having only "Test1"? In other words I will use contains('Test1') to find the correct row, now how to access its second column of that row?

Comment: @Pudd  thanks thats exactly what I was looking for. Just one more thing, how about to access the second next cell for example "153" in this case? Is this correct: .next("td").next("td").text() ?

Comment: You could use that, but it may become difficult to read.  You could try:
`.nextAll("td").eq(2)`
This will take all the proceeding `td` elements and then select the second.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
$('tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)').text();
```

Edit: Trim it, if needed.