# scraping table with R using RSelenium

Tags: java, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to scrape a table like [this](http://partnerlocator.symantec.com) (click on search then you will get a table of partners). I'd want to scrape the partner names. The problem is I don't know what kind of a table that is nor how to scrape it.

I am using `RSelenium` package. If it can be done using `rvest` then it would be much helpful.

So what kind of a table is this, is it possible to scrape it with `RSelenium` or `rvest` and if so, how?

```
ul="http://partnerlocator.symantec.com"
remDr$navigate(ul)
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "button")
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(10)
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "results")
unlist(webElem$getElementText())
```

But I get a very complex text output like this -

```
CDW\nCDW\n200 North Milwaukee Avenue\nVernon Hills ,Illinois ,60061\nUnited States\nDistance: 0 mi\nSymantec Platinum Partner\nCore Security - Platinum\nThreat Protection - Platinum\nCyber Security Services - Platinum\nInformation Protection - Platinum\nDLT Solutions\nDLT Solutions\n2411 Dulles Corner Park Suite 800\nHerndon ,Virginia ,20171\nUnited States\nDistance: 0 mi\nSymantec Platinum Partner\nInformation Protection - Platinum\nThreat Protection - Platinum\nCore Security - Platinum\nCyber Security Services - Platinum\nInsight Direct USA\nInsight Direct USA\n3480 Lotus Drive\nPlano ,Texas ,75075\nUnited States\nDistance: 0 mi\nSymantec Platinum Partner\nCyber Security Services - Platinum\nCore Security - Platinum\nThreat Prot.........
```

Comment: similar question mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953394/how-to-find-a-subset-of-cells-in-an-html-table-using-r-or-jquery

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a pretty basic HTML table collapsed into one line which can be expanded as such:

```
library(RSelenium)

checkForServer()
ul="http://partnerlocator.symantec.com"
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(ul)
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "button")
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(10)
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "results")
results <- webElem$getElementText()
results_chr <- unlist(strsplit(results[[1]], "\n"))

head(results_chr)
[1] "CDW"                           "CDW"                           "200 North Milwaukee Avenue"   
[4] "Vernon Hills ,Illinois ,60061" "United States"                 "Distance: 0 mi"
```

You might be able to return a cleaner result from the HTML table for that results page with `rvest` but I was unable to do so.