# Using rvest or RSelenium to create automated webscrape of table inside frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I know there's a great deal of resources/questions that deal with this subject but I have been trying for days and can't seem to figure it out. I have webscraped websites before but this one is causing me problems.

**The website:** [njaqinow.net](http://www.njaqinow.net/)

**What I want scraped:**  I would like to scrape the table under the "Current Status"->"Pollutants" tab. I would like to have this scraped every time the table is updated so I can use this information inside a shiny app I am creating.

[image]

**What I have tried:**  I have tried numerous different approaches but for simplicity I will show my most recent approach:

```
    library("rvest")
url<-"http://www.njaqinow.net"
webpage <- read_html(url)

test<-webpage%>%
  html_node("table")%>%
  html_table()
```

My guess is that this is way more complicated then I originally thought because it seems to me that the table is inside a frame. I am not a javascript/HTML pro so I am not entirely sure. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you tagged rselenium, but did not use it in the code. Is a rselenium solution also an option to you?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Yes it is. I tried using it but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can contribute a solution with RSelenium. I would show you how to navigate to that table and
get its content. For formatting the table content i provide a link to another question, but wont be
in the scope of this answer.

I think you have two challenges. Switch into a frame and switching between frames.
Switch into a frame is done by `remDr$switchToFrame()`.

Switching between frames is discussed here: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/155.
In your case:

```
remDr$switchToFrame("contents")
...
remDr$switchToFrame(NA)
remDr$switchToFrame("contentsi")
```

Full code would read:

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.njaqinow.net")
frame1 <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//frame[@id = 'contents']")
remDr$switchToFrame(frame1)
remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[text() = 'Current Status']")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[text() = 'POLLUTANTS']")$clickElement()

remDr$switchToFrame(NA)
remDr$switchToFrame("contentsi")
table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//table[@id = 'C1WebGrid1']")
table$getElementText()
```

For formatting a table you could look here:
[scraping table with R using RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049819/scraping-table-with-r-using-rselenium)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have a couple questions... 1.) how did you find the id 'C1WebGrid1' ? 2.) What is the best way to connect to the server? I keep getting errors.

Comment: 1) Within your browser right click on the desired element and choose inspect element. If necessary navigate up through the code until you hit the //table tag. 2) You mean remDr$open() fails? If yes, that also happens to me quite a lot. Thats very hard to debug from abroad. Maybe, you can ask another question for that if it doesnt exist already. Quite a lot of people would be interested in a stable process i guess ;)

Comment: When I do that it doesn't show up.. I'll figure it out tho. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NBE: you can use https://selectorgadget.com/ addon for Chrome to figure out the `C1WebGrid1` part